# postgREST inline function in select

Tags: postgrest

Is there any way to use inline functions in postgREST?

Something similar to:

```
https://api.example.com/mytable?select=id,geom:ST_AsEWKT(geom)
```

in this notation i recieve an error:

```
Searched for a foreign key relationship between 'mytable' and 'ST_AsEWKT' in the schema 'public', but no matches were found.
```

I need quite a simple query:

```
SELECT id, ST_AsEWKT(geom) AS geom FROM mytable
```

[ST_AsEWKT](https://postgis.net/docs/en/ST_AsEWKT.html) returns different representation of geom column.

---

Clean workaround is to use VIEWS with predefined columns:

```
CREATE VIEW vmytable AS SELECT id, ST_AsEWKT(geom) AS geom FROM mytable;
```

And then use posgREST api call on View table

```
https://api.example.com/vmytable?select=id,geom
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use subquery

```
SELECT id, (SELECT ST_AsEWKT(geom) FROM mytable) AS geom
```

You can also use a JSONPath expression to achieve the same result.

```
SELECT id, $.geom FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm searching for a solution using postgREST HTTP GET QUERY not SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [computed field](https://postgrest.org/en/latest/references/api/computed_fields.html) for this case:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ewkt_geom(anyelement)
RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT $1.geom;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Then do:

```
https://api.example.com/vmytable?select=id,ewkt_geom
```